# Is there a way to bind to a model from a parent scope without passing it to a directive’s isolate scope as an attribute?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

For an input defined in a directive's template, I would like to bind its model to a property on its parent scope.  Since multiple instances of the directive are on a page, an isolate scope is necessary.  I would like to avoid the necessity of having to pass the model as an attribute in the directive declaration.  It seems like this should be possible; but it's not working.

Directive:

```
catalogApp.directive("cmFieldFilterDtv", function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: "/templates/directives/field-filter-dtv.html",
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var field = attrs.fid;
            var fieldCamel = field.toLowerCaseFirst();
            scope.fid = 'filter' + field;
            scope.model = scope.$parent['filters.' + fieldCamel];
            scope.options = scope.$parent['configFilter' + field];
        }
    }

});
```

Template:

```
<input id="{{fid}}"
       ng-model="model"
       data-kendo-multi-select
       data-k-options="options" />
```

Page:

```
<cm-field-filter-dtv fid="PartNumber"></cm-field-filter-dtv>
<cm-field-filter-dtv fid="PartType"></cm-field-filter-dtv>
<cm-field-filter-dtv fid="Status"></cm-field-filter-dtv>
```

Selection changes to the input are not getting pushed (via model-binding) to parent scope's property.

Comment: Generally, I view directives as fully functional encapsulated units.  As such, there is no 'parent' scope per say.  It sounds like you want to add an undefined global dependency to your code and I usually consider that a bad idea.  That said, I think you can store the variable in the $rootscope instead of the $scope; then it should be accessible in both the directive and in the controller of the view that contains the directive.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you pass it in? In either case, you can do something like this:

```
catalogApp.directive("cmFieldFilterDtv", function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: "/templates/directives/field-filter-dtv.html",
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var field = attrs.fid;
            scope.fieldCamel = field.toLowerCaseFirst();
            scope.fid = 'filter' + field;
            scope.options = scope.$parent['configFilter' + field];
        }
    }

});
```

Template:

```
<input id="{{fid}}"
       ng-model="$parent['filters.' + fieldCamel]"
       data-kendo-multi-select
       data-k-options="options" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`scope.$parent` should give you access to the parent scope. It looks like the problem might be here...

```
scope.model = scope.$parent['filters.' + fieldCamel];
```

Does the parent scope have a property named `'filters.' + fieldCamel` (e.g. `$scope["filters.foo"]`)? Or does it have a property called `filters` that contains other values (e.g. `$scope.filters.foo`)? If it's the latter, you need to change it to...

```
scope.model = scope.$parent['filters'][fieldCamel];
```

Or

```
scope.model = scope.$parent.filters[fieldCamel];
```

But as others have mentioned, you don't want to couple a directive to its parent scope. Consider passing everything in.

Comment: `filters` is an object literal having the property `fieldCamel`.  However using the correct syntax doesn't solve this issue.  I'm not sure why; but I suspect it has something to do with the kendo-angular library.  Conversely if I pass the model to the directive via: `scope: { model: '=' }`, it works.  Since I have about 1000 of these directives to declare, I prefer passing just a single attribute rather than three attributes.  Passing the the model as the only attribute works and the other two parameters can be inferred from it.